# collation conflict between "Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI" and "Modern_Spanish_CI_AI"

Tags: sql-server, transact-sql

como puedo solucionar este conflicto en SQL Server:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between
> "Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI" and "Modern_Spanish_CI_AI" in the equal to
> operation.

Ocurre en el siguiente codigo:

```
CREATE TABLE #tSIRADIG (IDCodigo VARCHAR(10), Descripcion VARCHAR(60) )

INSERT INTO #tSIRADIG (IDCodigo, Descripcion)
VALUES ('30','Pago a Cuenta - RG 4815 - Ley 27541 - Art. 35 inc. d)')
INSERT INTO #tSIRADIG (IDCodigo, Descripcion)
VALUES ('31','Pago a Cuenta - RG 4815 - Ley 27541 - Art. 35 inc. e)')

INSERT INTO TIPO_PAGO_A_CUENTA (COD_SIRADIG, DESC_TIPO_PAGO_A_CUENTA)
SELECT A.IDCodigo, A.Descripcion 
FROM #tSIRADIG A 
RIGHT JOIN TIPO_PAGO_A_CUENTA B ON B.COD_SIRADIG = A.IDCodigo
WHERE B.COD_SIRADIG IS NULL
 
DROP TABLE #tSIRADIG
```

Gracias.

Comment: El problema parece estar aquí "B.COD_SIRADIG = A.IDCodigo" al comparar dos campos que se han definido con diferentes juegos de caracteres al crear las tablas. Esta respuesta de StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/1607725/2553194 te indica como resolverlo de la forma más fácil, aunque deberías asegurarte que al crear las tablas todos los campos de texto tuvieran asociado el mismo COLLATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al join agrégale la el código COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT

```
RIGHT JOIN TIPO_PAGO_A_CUENTA B ON B.COD_SIRADIG = A.IDCodigo COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

con eso debería bastar, has las pruebas y nos comentas.

Comment: Si, con ese código funciona perfecto, muchas gracias!

Comment: Es importante señalar que tener múltiples intercalaciones en una base de datos o que las bases de datos del sistema sean distintas a las de las bases de datos de usuario, puede traer problemas y es importante corregirlos de raíz en vez de tener que estar agregando código extra por todos lados.

Comment: Buen dato, muchas gracias